# Speed up Apache Derby DISTINCT query?

Tags: sql, performance, distinct, derby

I have a problem with Apache Derby. I imported the data from www.geonames.org and want to get the `DISTINCT` names.

The query `SELECT name FROM GEONAME` returns the results instantly.

The query `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM GEONAME` takes almost 20 minutes to complete.

How can I speed this up? There already is an index on the name table (`CREATE INDEX GEONAME_NAME_index ON GEONAME(NAME)`)

Comment: Both queries are exactly the same? Try `SELECT name FROM GEONAME GROUP BY name` instead.

Comment: Thank you, the `GROUP BY` query is indeed a lot faster.

Comment: Start learning about Derby performance analysis here: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/PerformanceDiagnosisTips